# WCF Service SOAP Error

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I have a WCF Service Application which when run locally on a dev machine works just fine.
As soon as it is hosted on IIS I get the following when trying to access it from code:

```
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at http://testsvc/Service1.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

SVCutil output gives me this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://testsvc/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

If I navigate to http://testsvc/Service1.svc I am prompted with the default page indicating all is ok.

Here is my service's web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Error from event viewer:

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/43683950
 Exception: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The service '/IService1.svc' does not exist. ---> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: The service '/IService1.svc' does not exist.
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 1672
```

Not sure what else to try here.

Comment: Have you checked the event viewer on the machine with IIS to see if there were any issues logged there?

Comment: Just did. See above for error.

Comment: Can you post the code where you make the call?  It looks like it's trying to reach `/IService1.svc` instead of `/Service1.svc`.

Comment: This is where it errors out: `ServiceReference2.Service1Client sc = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client();
            ServiceReference2.getTeamsResponse x = await sc.getTeamsAsync("myTeams");
            this.DataGrid.ItemsSource = x.getTeamsResult;`

Comment: Figured it out. It was something so silly and yet you could never figure it out from the error. My app is a Windows Store App and in the Package.appxmanifest needed to toggle on more options such as Private Networks, Shared User Certificates. That just made it work, hopefully this can help others.

Comment: You should post your solution with the details (i.e., what options, etc) as the answer.  You can self-accept it after a delay.